# Application Trust Level on Network Drive for Nhibernate C# Application

Tags: c#, activerecord, .net-3.5, full-trust

**Scenario:** I have a C# application that uses Click-Once to install(puts an icon on the desktop that points to the application) itself on computers on the network. I have recently been integrating NHibernate into the program and everything runs smooth on my box. Its ready for internal testing and I need to put it on our network share (Same share as production, different folder).

**Problem:** When I place it on the network share and run it I recieve an error saying the application cannot run in partial trust.

**Question:** I have googled this to no end and every solution seems to talk about a Web Application experiencing this. Is there anyway I can set the application to run in full trust mode on a network share. Setting the folder/exe to full trust? Is this simply allowing "Full Control" in the security tab of my applications properties?

Here is the error I recieve when running the application
[image]

Thanks for any input

Comment: Ended up recompiling everything with partial trust and it now works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the security policy on the client machine using CasPol.exe or the configuration tool in Administrative Tools.

- [Code Access Security Policy Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/cb6t8dtz%28v=vs.90%29)
- [Using CasPol to Fully Trust a Share](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217123743/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx)
- [.NET Framework Configuration Tool (Mscorcfg.msc)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/2bc0cxhc%28v=vs.90%29)
- [Code Access Security Policy (CASPOL.exe) GUI Utility](https://brandonpotter.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/code-access-security-policy-caspol-exe-gui-utility/)

Alternatively, you can upgrade to .net 4.0, which [gets rid of all this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/framework/windows-identity-foundation/security-changes).

**EDIT**: You can also try adding [`[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx)to the referenced assembly.

Comment: @Slaks - +1 More people need to know about caspol.exe. Could you provide a link to more info concerning the changes to .NET 4?

Comment: @Pieter: [Security Changes in the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103.aspx)

Comment: @Slaks, Is there anyway this could be run remotely/automagically without user interaction. Forcing every user to do this isn't really an option since we don't necessarily know who will be running it.

Comment: @Gage: Ask your IT infrastructure.

Comment: @Slaks, Tried adding that to the assembly with no luck. Recompiled Nhibernate and Castle to allow that and still doesn't work. I would consider trying .Net 4.0 if it worked with VS 2008. Can't justify the upgrade to 2010

Comment: @Gage: Installing .Net 3.5 **SP1** on the _client_ machines should also help.  (It changes the default policy)

Comment: @Slaks, the clients have .Net 3.5 SP1 installed, the only option I'm left with right now is to contact IT like you suggested. I'll post the progress I make. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Putting an Icon on the desktop that points to a network share does not sound like Click-once.

But this 'problem' should be solved from Fx 3.5 SP1 onwards.

Comment: It's an application reference that is puts on the desktop. Thought it was an icon, my bad. I am using .Net 3.5

Comment: And is it SP1? Would make it a different question.

Comment: I believe so I have 3.5 SP1 installed but it only shows .Net 3.5 in my project setttings.